# aspose cells.getRows().getCount() and cells.getCount() keeps increasing for a excel worksheet

Tags: java, aspose

My excel has one worksheet with three rows and two columns (first row is header row, 2nd, 3rd is data row), I use aspose com.aspose.cells.Cells class and get the row count and number of cells as follow:

```
Cells cells = uploadExcel.getWorksheets().get(0).getCells();
logger.info("cells.getRows().getCount()="+cells.getRows().getCount());
logger.info("cells.getCount()="+cells.getCount());
for (int i = 1; i <= cells.getRows().getCount(); i++) {
                logger.info("cells.getRows().getCount()="+cells.getRows().getCount());
                logger.info("cells.getCount()="+cells.getCount());
                logger.info("cells.get(i, 1).getStringValue().trim()="+cells.get(i, 1).getStringValue().trim());
}
```

But I found the console output, the cells.getRows().getCount() and cells.getCount() keep increasing after the first three loop as follow:

> 00:26:30,601 INFO  [com.frw.object.repository.EXM103] (default task-2) cells.getRows().getCount()=3
>
> 00:26:32,606 INFO  [com.frw.object.repository.EXM103] (default task-2) cells.getCount()=6
>
> 00:26:37,300 INFO  [com.frw.object.repository.EXM103] (default task-2) cells.getRows().getCount()=3
>
> 00:26:39,536 INFO  [com.frw.object.repository.EXM103] (default task-2) cells.getCount()=6
>
> 00:26:43,731 INFO  [com.frw.object.repository.EXM103] (default task-2) cells.get(i, 1).getStringValue().trim()=15/01/2020
>
> 00:26:55,031 INFO  [com.frw.object.repository.EXM103] (default task-2) cells.getRows().getCount()=3
>
> 00:26:56,617 INFO  [com.frw.object.repository.EXM103] (default task-2) cells.getCount()=6
>
> 00:27:03,795 INFO  [com.frw.object.repository.EXM103] (default task-2) cells.get(i, 1).getStringValue().trim()=16/02/2020
>
> 00:27:07,173 INFO  [com.frw.object.repository.EXM103] (default task-2) cells.getRows().getCount()=3
>
> 00:27:08,629 INFO  [com.frw.object.repository.EXM103] (default task-2) cells.getCount()=6
>
> 00:27:13,627 INFO  [com.frw.object.repository.EXM103] (default task-2) cells.get(i, 1).getStringValue().trim()=
>
> 00:27:21,966 INFO  [com.frw.object.repository.EXM103] (default task-2) cells.getRows().getCount()=4
>
> 00:27:23,124 INFO  [com.frw.object.repository.EXM103] (default task-2) cells.getCount()=7
>
> 00:28:19,353 INFO  [com.frw.object.repository.EXM103] (default task-2) cells.get(i, 1).getStringValue().trim()=
>
> 00:28:26,331 INFO  [com.frw.object.repository.EXM103] (default task-2) cells.getRows().getCount()=5
>
> 00:28:28,354 INFO  [com.frw.object.repository.EXM103] (default task-2) cells.getCount()=8

why the cells.getRows().getCount(), cells.getCount() keep increasing after the first three iteration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is expected behavior for those APIs. There are some other APIs which have the same behavior, such as Cells[int row, int column], RowCollection[int row]…etc. Actually, for these APIs, Aspose.Cells have to instantiate the corresponding objects in the cells model so that you may manipulate data with the objects conveniently.

However, if you only need to access existing objects, you may use methods such as Row.getCellOrNull()/Cells.checkCell()/checkRow()…etc. If the returned object is null, then the corresponding object has not been instantiated in the cells model. However, the best way to iterate existing objects is to use the Iterator, such as Row.iterator()/Cells.iterator(). See the following sample code segments for your reference:

e.g

Sample code:

```
1)
//Load sample workbook
Workbook wb = new Workbook(dirPath + "sample.xlsx");

//Access first worksheet
Worksheet ws = wb.getWorksheets().get(0);

//Access cells iterator
Iterator itrat = ws.getCells().iterator();

//Print cells name in iterator
while(itrat.hasNext())
{
    Cell cell = (Cell)itrat.next();

    System.out.println(cell.getName() + ": " + cell.getStringValue().trim());
}


2) 
Workbook book = new Workbook("sample.xlsx");
Worksheet sheet = book.getWorksheets().get(0);
Range range = sheet.getCells().getMaxDisplayRange();//You may also create your desired range (in the worksheet) using, e.g sheet.getCells().createRange("A1", "J11");
Iterator rangeIterator = range.iterator();
while(rangeIterator.hasNext())
{
Cell cell = (Cell)rangeIterator.next();
//your code goes here.
}
```

Hope, this helps a bit.

PS. I am working as Support developer/ Evangelist at Aspose.

Comment: anyway, I use for (int i = 1; i <= cells.getMaxDataRow(); i++) {... to loop the row and found cells.getMaxDataRow() will not be changed during the loop

Comment: yes, this is also good way to loop through whole data range in the worksheet via MaxDataRow and MaxDataColumn attributes. MaxDataRow/MaxDataColumn will give you the farthest row/col indices (zero based) which has data in it.